# how can i filter array in swift 5 for search text in searchbar?

Tags: ios, arrays, filter, uisearchbar, swift5

I am going to search from tableview and for that i used array.filter(), but i can not get any suggestion related to function's parameter, i got "NSArray.Element self", how can add my required parameter to function. i am not able to get a any function like "prefix" or "replaceString" in parameter, so i how can solve this issue?

here is my code,

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate
{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String)
{
searchCoin = ArrData.filter ({ $0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to filter and what does `$0` represent?

Comment: want to filter array for search text from searchbar, here is my code you can see

Answer (score 1):

To check if any string element in the array contains the search text. Be it prefix, suffix or in between the string

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate
{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String)
    {
       searchCoin = ArrData.filter({ $0.contains(find: searchText)})
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

OR

To check if the any string element in the array has prefix equal to search text

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate
{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String)
    {
       searchCoin = ArrData.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(searchText)})
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `$0` responds to `contains`?

Comment: @vadian $0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText. This actually means she is trying to check if any element in the array has searchText as the prefix which means its a string and responds to contains.

Comment: Thank you Swati, out of countless answers related to this topic you actually gave the correct one. BTW, the Swift 5 version is: let searchCoin = newArray.filter({ $0.contains(searchText!)})

Answer (score 1):

Swati is correct. Swift 5 has slightly different syntax but it's basically this. searchCoin is a new array filter of the original data array that you are searching.

```
let searchCoin = dataArray.filter({ $0.contains(searchText!)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using:

```
let searchCoin = dataArray.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
```